# troubles with opencv_createsamples

Tags: opencv

I've tried to make a .vec file using the opencv_cratesamples.
This is what I wrote in the Command Promt window:

```
C:\Users\Dan>C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_createsamples -info C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTER_POS.txt -num 6 -w 50 -h 50 -vec LETTERS.vec
```

The .txt file is:

```
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTERS_POS\A.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTERS_POS\B.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTERS_POS\C.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTERS_POS\D.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTERS_POS\E.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTERS_POS\F.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
```

The problem I get is:

```
Unable to open image: C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\LETTERS_POS\Aletter.jpg
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -9 () in cvSetImageROI, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 3000
```

What do I do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Double check your code, you are appending the path from TXT to the TXT path: Unable to open image: C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\**C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\**LETTERS_POS\Aletter.jpg add your code if you need help.

Comment: OK, I modified the .txt file to:  \LETTERS_POS\A.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
\LETTERS_POS\B.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
\LETTERS_POS\C.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
\LETTERS_POS\D.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
\LETTERS_POS\E.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
\LETTERS_POS\F.jpg 1 0 0 50 50
Thank you.

Comment: Now I get: Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters. When I enter: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_TRAIN -vec C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER.vec -bg C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_NEG.txt -numPos 4 -numNeg 10 -numStages 15 -minHitRate 0.995 -w 50 -h 50 -featureType LBP -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcldxBufSize 1024 what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please open a new question regarding this new error. Be sure to include the relevant code that reads/writes your files, preferably as a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).